# Home workstation cloud computing solution on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, replication, xen, kvm, eucalyptus

I want to make a cloud computing testing environment on my in-house network. I'm using Ubuntu (just to work on; i don't want to watch Gentoo compile screens all time:) and I plan to make an Eucalyptus installation for a cloud platform. I want to get the most of my Core2Quad and Core2Duo machines:) What I need a cloud for?

- Mysql replication and sharding
- Load ballancing testing
- Gearman web application scaling
- ... and another multi-machine solutions

I'm on my way to select a hypervisor for this solution between Xen, KVM and probably OpenVZ. I'd like to hear all you advises concerning this technologies. Possible requirements:

- Support virtual machine creating from templates
- Support several virtual machines running with ssh access
- Ability to load both from HDD images and raw disk partitions
- Not very long learning curve
- It would be very good if one had some kind of GUI (both desktop and web interfaces are acceptable)

As for my previous searches: found this http://virt-manager.et.redhat.com/ tool available. and this tutorial http://www.howtoforge.com/kvm-guest-management-with-virt-manager-on-ubuntu-8.10-p2 - some kind of relevancy present. Some good info was found here - http://lwn.net/Articles/330872/ and here - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Eucalyptus-Jaunty

Feel free to say your thoughts about it and provide additional information you concern relevant. Thank you.

Comment: found some info like http://www.howtoforge.com/kvm-and-openvz-virtualization-and-cloud-computing-with-proxmox-ve, but don't know if it fits my needs yet.

Comment: useful: http://kiranmurari.wordpress.com/2010/03/19/uec-cc-nc-single-machine/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you plan to use Ubuntu or in fact, the eucalyptus packages, take into account that by default they now have moved from Xen to KVM. KVM requires your machines to support hardware assisted virtualization (Intel VT or AMD-V), so check first your processor capabilities before going with KVM. If you prefer/require Xen, I would suggest to move to Debian Lenny + eucalyptus compiled from source. AFAIK, OpenVZ is not supported by eucalyptus by default.

Comment: I chose my CPUs with IntelVT support :)